# Python--Repeat rows in a csv/DataFrame by value in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to repeat the rows in a csv/DataFrame by the number found in a column titled "Mstg". The output should be a csv file with ~0.5M rows (it's large!).
The csv file has the following columns: "Year", "Month", "Hour", "Price 1", "Price 2"...."Mstg", "GW". All fields in the columns are identified as numbers (either floats or integers).

I tried the following, but it's not working. Could it be that the column or numbers in the column by which I want the rows to be repeated, is not recognized?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
project = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("path",header=0, sep=',')

#change columns names "Mstg" and "GW" to integers 
cols1 = ['Mstg']
cols2 = ['GW']
project[cols1] = project[cols1].applymap(np.int64)
project[cols2] = project[cols2].applymap(np.int64)


#repeat rows by number in Mstg column
 project_expanded =project.loc[np.repeat(project.index.values,project.Mstg)]
```

When I run pd.DataFrame.describe(project_expanded), the console doesn't show anything.

Comment: Note that the code works until the last line.

Comment: I solved the issue. My csv file was not properly indexed, so the np.repeat function didn't work. I reset the index using df2=df.reset_index()  and the last line of code finally worked!